# python 2.7 shows up when running where pip3

Tags: python, macos, pip

As the title states, I'm seeing an incorrect version of python showing when I check `pip3 --version`

```
pip 20.2.4 from /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-20.2.4-py2.7.egg/pip (python 2.7)
```

A few other checks:

1. which pip3: /usr/local/bin/pip3
2. which python3: /usr/bin/python3

I'm not sure how this happened so some insight here would be great. This is causing issues as I'm not installing any packages with python 3.

Comment: can you show the output of `pip3 --version`?

Comment: @AdamSmith: Added

Comment: maybe `brew install python`, that way python is python3, pip is pip3, python2 is python2, and pip2 is pip2

Comment: an alias for `python3` can be added to `.bash_profile` so when typing `python` for example, the correct version will be run

Comment: @etch_45 - I don't like that solution.  It's a hack, and it's bound to be forgotten about and lead to a lot of confusion down the road.  Best to get things truly right on your system.

Comment: I like the idea of installing new versions with `brew`.  That's how I install new Pythons.  Then I use `venv` and the `venv-register` plug-in to register with `venv` the versions I've installed with `brew`.

Comment: @KetZoomer - That did the trick. Any chance you can submit an answer which an explanation why. I didn't see this solution anywhere online.

Comment: @MadhavThaker, posted an answer :)

Answer (score 1):

You have two ways to fix this that I know of. I ran into this as well:

1. Use `python3 -m pip install ...` and forget about it
2. Actually understand what's going on - `pip` is actually a scipt that gets invoked by a python executable defined in its shebang:

```
❯ cat $(which pip)
#!/Users/me/anaconda/bin/python

# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import re
import sys

from pip._internal.cli.main import main

if __name__ == '__main__':
    sys.argv[0] = re.sub(r'(-script\.pyw?|\.exe)?$', '', sys.argv[0])
    sys.exit(main())
```

Let's do an experiment. This pip corresponds to my python3.8 installation. I'll create a python3.6 version for the sake of demonstration.

```
❯ conda create -n p3.6 python=3.6 anaconda
```

Then we change the shebang to the new 3.6 installation:

```
#!/Users/me/anaconda/envs/p3.6/bin/python
```

And run `pip --version` on the `pip` that belongs to my python 3.8 installation:

```
❯ pip --version
pip 20.1.1 from /Users/rzhang/anaconda/envs/p3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip (python 3.6)
```

As you can see it shows that it points to this python3.6 python instead.

The reason this is the case is because if you look at the `sys.argv[0] = ...` line, it adopts the current python used to invoke the script. Modifying that before going into `main()` "picks" the python selected from shebang. Try changing that to the realpath of your python installation.

Now if you **really** want to fix the problem by understanding what's really going on, chances are your python interpreter links are all screwed up from a weird sequence of installations. It may be that the file in your shebang is actually a symlink that is not actually pointing at the correct installation, and you should fix that on a per-situation basis. There is no easy solution other than to untangle the installation paths of your multiple python interpreters.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

If you do have the `brew` package manager, you can do `brew install python`

If you don't, you can run `/bin/bash -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install.sh)"` to install it, then do the above step.

What this does, is the following,

```
python -> Python 3
python3 -> Python 3
python2 -> Python 2
pip -> Pip 3
pip2 -> Pip 2
pip3 -> Pip 3
```

This way, `python` point to python3, but you also still have access to python 2 (by using the command `python2`)

Comment: please upvote, and if it was the best answer, mark as the answer